# PHP page with dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php page that updates scores in a MySQL database. Currently the page displays the value from the db. I want to change that to a dropdown list (0-9) that will then update the database. I'm a newbie and can't figure this out. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far. I have truncated the code;

```
<h1>UPDATE SCORES</h1>
<form method="post" action="add_scores.php" >
 <table width="60%" cellpadding="15" style="font-family: verdana, arial; border: #FFCC99 1px solid">
        <tr> 
            <td height="28" colspan="24" align="center" style="font-size: 44px">
            <strong><li>1st Quarter:</li></strong><br>
            <strong><font color="#DB2824">NFC: </font></strong><input size="4" maxlength="1" name="away_first" value="<?php echo $record['away_first'];?>"/>
            <strong><font color="#232B85">AFC: </font></strong><input size="1" maxlength="1" name="home_first" value="<?php echo $record['home_first'];?>"/>
            <br><br>
```

Comment: What are the contents of add_scores.php? There is not enough information here for someone to help you.

Comment: use `<select>` to present dropdown in HTML page

Answer (score 0):

Replace your inputs with something like this:

```
<select name="away_first">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    if ($record['away_first'] == $i) {
        echo '<option selected>' . $i . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option>' . $i . '</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

This is just an example, nothing I've tested.
If you want the form to autopost you could just add a simple onchange-listener to it, either inline or in a script block/file.

Comment: I tried your example above but the drop-down does not open. It is there but when I click on it there are no options.

Comment: Sorry @user2316354, used plus instead of dot. Stupid mistake. Should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

didn't test it, but this function should generate the code for you:

```
<?php
function generateSelect($name, $value) {
    $str = "<select name='$name'>";
    foreach(\range(0,9) as $i) {
        $selected = $i == $value ? 'selected' : '';
        $str .= "<option value='$i' $selected>$i</option>";
    }
    $str .= "</select>";
    return $str;
}
```